# Install yesod with stack on a 512 MB-memory server

Tags: ubuntu, memory, memory-limit, openvz

I'm trying to install yesod in a server running Ubuntu 14.04 with stack, running:

`stack install yesod-bin cabal-install --install-ghc`

The problem is, the system runs out of memory and installation is aborted. Is there any way I can do this so that it doesn't take up so much memory?

Additionally, I'm running on OpenVZ, which seems to make it impossible to use a swap file.

Thanks.

Comment: Figure out which memory limit got hit in `/proc/user_beancounters` (see the `failcnt` column) and ask your host about temporarily raising it.